# UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 0-15: surrogates not allowed

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am having trouble trying to print the result of a unicode here's what i have tried

```
data = u"\ud835\udc6a\ud835\udc89\ud835\udc90\ud835\udc84\ud835\udc8c"
result = data.encode('utf-8', 'surrogatepass') 
#b'\xed\xa0\xb5\xed\xb1\xaa\xed\xa0\xb5\xed\xb2\x89\xed\xa0\xb5\xed\xb2\x90\xed\xa0\xb5\xed\xb2\x84\xed\xa0\xb5\xed\xb2\x8c'
result.decode('utf-8')
#UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

According to Charbase, `\udc90` is an invalid character
https://charbase.com/dc90-unicode-invalid-character

I get to convert the unicode through this website: https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php under the section "Decode/Unescape Unicode Entities"

Here's a screenshot of the result

[image]

How can i print this unicode out ? I am receiving data from an API and wants to store it in MySQL database. Currently, the result in MySQL database is ???????????

Comment: What is it the origin of the first line? I think the problem should be tacked here: by not putting surrogates in a python string. If it is autogenerated, just put it as binary escapes (and let the 'decode' to interpret the codes).

Comment: Second note: Are you sure you are using Python3? On python 3, do not add string suffix `u`.

Comment: `"\ud835\udc6a\ud835\udc89\ud835\udc90\ud835\udc84\ud835\udc8c"` this is the exact string i get when i retrieve the data from API. I am using python 3. Problem occur when i try to store that string into MySQL database, in the database it is displayed as `?????????????` So i ended up using `json.dumps(data)` before saving to the database, and use `json.loads(data)` when i retrieve it from the database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What that website presents are likely JSON format escape sequences containing surrogate pairs, which are really a UTF-16 thing, which Javascript treats strings as under the hood. The same raw string literals aren't valid in Python. What you want is not to let Python interpret the escape sequences, but create a string which contains escape sequences:

```
>>> r'\ud835\udc6a\ud835\udc89\ud835\udc90\ud835\udc84\ud835\udc8c'
'\\ud835\\udc6a\\ud835\\udc89\\ud835\\udc90\\ud835\\udc84\\ud835\\udc8c'
```

Since this is Javascript/JSON format, use the `json` module to decode it:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(r'"\ud835\udc6a\ud835\udc89\ud835\udc90\ud835\udc84\ud835\udc8c"')
''
```

The way Python would encode this string as escape sequences is:

```
>>> print(''.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ascii'))
\U0001d46a\U0001d489\U0001d490\U0001d484\U0001d48c
```

Comment: Pedantic mode: Python strings allow surrogates (when used with proper decoder, but this decoder doesn not help here). They are seldom used, e.g. when reading `sys.argv`, as "escape" (see PEP383).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure Python can treat those directly as well, I just haven't needed it so far and didn't feel like digging deep enough here to find the right codec, since I believe this is mostly a matter of misunderstanding the difference between Javascript literals and Python to begin with. If you can add these details, by all means, please do.

Comment: As you see on initial like: the surrogates were already put into a string. You instead changed string prefix `u` to `r`. IMHO the problem should be handled earlier (by not putting surrogates in Python code, which seems a "manual" decoding). I asked details to OP.

Comment: I'm guessing they're experimenting with JSON and are copy-pasting strings into Python willy nilly, but yeah, that's just a hunch…